# Is google fusedlocationapi free to use?

Tags: android, android-location, fusedlocationproviderapi, android-fusedlocation

Can anyone please tell me is fusedlocationapi free to use or alike other google api services it has some free request limits. I have googled this a lot but nowhere it was mentioned, if anybody know about it please tell me i am searching for this from last 2 days but haven't found anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is free to use. There are no usage limits.

The API is a device-local API. All it costs to use it is battery power and the hardware that the device provides. The external hardware that makes location fixing possible (GPS satellites etc) is active regardless. Your app fixing a location doesn't cost them.